# When switching between two scenes: MissingReferenceException: The object of type '...' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it

Tags: unity, unity-ui

I recreated the problem in a new project to check and test the problem, but I don't understand it.

Two scenes:

### First scene

A GameObject with this script that simply jumps to the second scene.

*script1_S1.cs*

```
void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)) SceneManager.LoadScene("Scene2", LoadSceneMode.Single);
}
```

### Second scene

Two GameObjects with two different scripts.

The first script can go back to scene1 or invoke an event.

*script1_S2.cs*

```
public delegate void OnMyEvent ();
public static event OnMyEvent onMyEvent;

void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)) SceneManager.LoadScene("Scene1", LoadSceneMode.Single);
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S)) onMyEvent?.Invoke();
}
```

The second script registers the event and loads the `rootVisualElement` of the `UIDocument` included as a component in the same `GameObject` of this script.

*script2_S2.cs*

```
private void Awake() {
    ScriptCube1.onMyEvent += () => { Log(); };
}

public void Log() {
    gameObject.GetComponent<UIDocument>().rootVisualElement.style.display = DisplayStyle.Flex;
    Debug.Log("Cliccked");
}
```

#### Steps to reproduce the error

If from the first scene I press `A` I go to the second. In the second one I press `S` and the console prints `Clickcked`, and everything works fine. But if I go back to scene 1, and again to scene 2, if I hit `S`, I get this error: `MissingReferenceException: The object of type '...' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.`.

`SceneManager.LoadScene` Shouldn't it load the scene as if it were the first time? What am I missing?

Thank you.

---

*After writing all the question I have a doubt. But maybe the problem is that the event has not been deregistered? the error is on the `gameObject` as if it didn't exist anymore. With `SceneManager.LoadScene("Scene1", LoadSceneMode.Single);` shouldn't it unregister all events in `Scene2`? Should I unregister all events? or do I have to use `SceneManager.UnloadScene` explicitly?*

Comment: I'm not 100% sure in this but the event is more like a pointer to the function you are trying to call. While logically it is the same function (`Log()`), the second time you are loading scene2, `onMyEvent` has now two reference to `Log()` since you never removed the listener. The first one still points to the now already destroyed old scene, as the error says. I don't think UnloadScene helps, since the scene does not know where your events are actually pointing at

Comment: @Zibelas It is sure that the event is not destroyed. If I leave only the log command `Debug.Log("Clicked");` at the second loading of the scene2 the console prints `Clicked` twice. The solution I found is this; in `script1_S2.cs` destroy the event with the `GameObject`: `private void OnDestroy() { onMyEvent = null; }`

Comment: The event is not destroyed, it is about what the underlying function that gets registered on it. And while setting it to null will work, cleaner would be to remove the listener to just the exact function. While this makes no difference in this case, if you ever register more than one function to the same event, you might not want/ need remove all of them

Comment: If you solved your problem, be sure to post the solution as an Answer below.

Comment: @Zibelas I agree, but it's intentional, all events in this scene are registered at the beginning of the scene and must die with the scene. [at]DMGregory Sure, I tried it on the real project too, it works!

Comment: The static should be the culprit, thats why when you reload the same scene, you still have data on it from the time before since it is the same onMyEvent as last time.

Comment: @Zibelas I still had the test project open, I immediately did a test and if it's not static, the event is destroyed with the scene! If you want to write the answer, I gladly accept it. You helped me understand, which is more important than the solution itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all comes down to the static. It makes the life both easier and harder. Since onMyEvent is static, there is only one of it. That means, even if you destroy the scene and reload it, you get the same onMyEvent with all the values assigned from the last scene back.

Since you are assigning a function to it on Awake, you point now twice to the Log function. This can cause errors since to what we originally pointed might got already destroyed.

The clean way would be to remove the listener/ subscription in the OnDestroy of the scene or set the event null if you are sure there are no side effects (since there can always be the option that other scripts are as well adding their listeners to it). Another option is to remove the static modifier, a new scene would create a new, empty version of the event.